# Android app photo uploading problems

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a newbie on android app development. My team and I are creating an app that uses photo gallery folders to upload the photo. The app is able to take a photo and upload that photo immediately. But specifically with samsung devices, when I try to upload photo from camera folder, app either crashes or uploads a white page. When I try a different folder from the gallery besides than camera folder, that works perfect too. It gives this error only with camera folder. I tested my app with different nexus devices and it worked absolutely perfect. I have been searching this any where and everywhere. I wrote all the codes on Android Studio along with Java and XML. Did anyone have the same issue and were able to solve? I really need a guidance. Thanks for your time and your attention.

Here is my Java onGalleryClick method:

```
public void onGalleryClick(View v) {

    isCameraReleased = true;
    //TODO
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
            "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
}
```

Comment: show your upload code.

Comment: I had similar problem using LG devices. Which application opens photos gallery ?

Comment: I added my onGalleryClick method.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out with implementing Picasso library. Finally I can access to Camera folder( Some of the devices it is DCIM) when I got into gallery option. I believe Samsung devices has a very low virtual memories and somehow it doesn't allow you to see the imageView on the android app that you create. Basically I created a very simple button on android studio and it's called activity_main.xml. Which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ImageView>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonLoadPicture"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:onClick="loadImagefromGallery"
    android:text="Load Picture" >
  </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Afterward, I created MainActivity.java that gives all the functionality. Which is:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;
   String imgDecodableString;

   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}

}
```

And this is the line of code that you have to add on AndroidManifest file:

```
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Here is the tricky part of everything. in your build.gradle(Module:app) you are going to add 
     compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3' at dependencies section.

After you gotta add

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Picasso.with(this)
            .load("https://cms-assets.tutsplus.com/uploads/users/21/posts/19431/featured_image/CodeFeature.jpg")
            .into(imageView);
```

And there you go!Please take a look http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149